# Parent/Child resource classes - annotations don't work in parent class

Tags: java, jersey

I don't have any specific examples in front of me right now, but I've had this issue in the past.

When I have a resource that extends another class and utilizes annotations, can the base class have annotations that are read as if they're part of the child class?  I've tried to do this in some scenarios and it doesn't ever seem to work.  Is there some way to make this possible?  Is this a scope issue with no `@Path` being defined for the base class?

```
@Path("/workflow")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public class WorkflowResource extends BaseWorkflowResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/getAllActive")
    public Collection<WorkflowEntity> getActive () {
        return MyClass.getAllActive();
    }
}

//THIS CALL WON'T BE AVAILABLE
public class BaseWorkflowResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/getMyString")
    public String getActiveString () {
        return "my string";
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Sorry - I wasn't trying to compile this code, it was just meant as an example to showcase the scenario.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't work. I would assume that jersey uses reflection to get all public methods of a class, ie. `Class#getMethods()` which returns the methods of all superclasses.

Answer (score 0):

This method

```
public Collection<WorkflowEntity> getActive()
```

will override this method

```
public String getActive()
```

This is not a matter of JAX-RS but of plain Java. Both methods have the same signature (name, parameters).

Try using different method signatures in parent and child class.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't trying to compile this code, it was just meant as an example to showcase the scenario.